# Prove this centralizer is abelian

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

> Assume $G$ is a group, $x\in G$, $x$ of not the identity of $G$, and $C_G(x)$ is the centralizer of $x$ in $G$. Prove that if $\mid C_G(x) \mid =pq$ for some primes $p$ and $q$, then $C_G(x)$ is abelian.

Class equation: $$1= \sum_y \frac{1}{C_{C_G(x)}(y)}$$ $C_{C_G(x)}(x)=C_{C_G(x)}(e)=pq.$   $C_{C_G(x)}(y)=1, p, q$ or $pq$. $C_{C_G(x)}(y)=1$ is not possible.
$\implies \exists k_1, k_2, k_3$ non negative s.t. $pq= k_1p+k_2q+k_3+2.$

Please give a hint as to how to prove $k_1=k_2=0$. Please do not give solution. Thanks!

Comment: $x \in Z(C_G(x))$, so $C_G(x)$ cannot have trivial centre, so $C_G(x))/Z(C_G(x))$ is cyclic, which implies that $C_G(x)$ is abelian.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks